# Does Facebook's Android App uses ListView or is there another way to create that nice list of posts in a timeline?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Does Facebook's Android App uses ListView or is there another way to create that nice list of posts in a timeline?

Also it's currently very fast and when u scroll very fast up and down it doesn't display any sign of reloading images or graphics unlike the normal ListView when you're using dynamic image loader and caching.

Comment: A while back I opened the app to find it without styles and blue/purple links. Unless they changed it, that tells me it's Web based.

Comment: It was a web view but that was in version 2, starting from v. 3+ it became 100% native

Comment: @Phix yeah, they just relaunched a native version this week, but you're correct in that previously it was just a web wrapper.

Comment: @Shehabox https://m.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10151189598933920

Comment: Ah... Interesting. Good to know!

Comment: @kcoppock I see, so according to their note, they wrote their own ListView which is more efficient as they say, and I believe they should've done so cause the normal ListView and its Recycler isn't really efficient.

Comment: @Shehabox I disagree; in my experience the stock one is perfectly fine if you use it correctly. It's possible theirs is more efficient, but I'd trust Google's Android code over Facebook's until I saw proof otherwise.

Comment: @kcoppock in my social app there are 5 different types of list items (very different not just colors or icons), when the list becomes really big (like 100 items each of size ~500-600 dip) the ListView starts swapping ListItems when I scroll, this happens more often on small devices like GalaxyMini/Pocket With low speed processors, but it happens less often with my Galaxy S2, also it consumes a lot of memory and such small devices have a way too low memory.

Comment: Are you using the `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` methods to make sure the recycler is returning the correct type of layout for the view?

Comment: Yes, sure cause without using them the list is messed up immediately even if it has 4 or 5 items only.

Answer (score 0):

It could be multiple LinearLayouts inside a ScrollView. The feed is of different types and can have different layouts, the layouts can be dynamically pushed onto a scrollview.

As far as the scrolling and performance is concerned, i think the feed is prefetched. thats a good practice if you do not want the user to reach the end of the listview for it to load more data.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know answer but i can provide you a cheat code for this.

Download Facebook app apk file and after that decompile it

1. Change the extension of facebookapp.apk to facebookapp.zip, click Yes to any dialog appears. By this you can view manifest and xml layout files but code is still inaccessible.
2. Than their you found a classes.dex file, that use dex2jar to convert classes.dex files to classes.jar.
3. Use Java Decompiler (jd-gui) or eclipse to view those class files.

You can do this to any app,
By this you may not get the accurate code but get the basic idea how app works.

For any problem refer to google also for tools need you can find easily by google.